# Ability to register and sign more than one Fido U2F security key

Tags: javascript, fido-u2f

How do you add the ability to register and sign more than one security key on a website/application

Answer (score 0):

How do you request all registered keys and only sign one of them? Well, you need two node packages. [u2f](https://www.npmjs.com/package/u2f) for server-side and [u2f-api](https://www.npmjs.com/package/u2f-api) for server-side.

When a user wants to register one of their keys onto your website; your backend must make a request to the browser.

Server-slide script

```js
const u2f = require('u2f');
const APP_ID = "https://..."; // your website URL, must be https

/**
 * Server requesting. You can use Express.js to send the request
 */
const request = () => u2f.request(APP_ID);

/**
 * @param {{
 *  version: String,
 *  appId: String,
 *  challenge: String
 * }} request The request object from the previous function
 * @param response Response from U2F key
 */
const verifyRegistration = (request, response) => {
  const result = u2f.checkRegistration(request, response);

  if (result.successful) {
    /**
     * store the result.publicKey and result.keyHandle
     * to your user database associated with this user
     * because we are going to need it later when the user is
     * logging into your website with the same security key.
     * I recommend you encrypt the public key and key handle
     */
  } else {
    // failed
  };
};

/**
 * When the user wants to login with the security key
 * @param {String} userID The user's ID 
 */
const sign = (userID) => {
  /**
   * get the user object from your database using the userID
   * and map all of the user keys into an array
   */

  return userSecurityKeys.map((key) => u2f.request(APP_ID, key.keyHandle));
}

const verifyAuthentication = (userID, request, response) => {
  /**
   * Quite similar to checkRegistration
   */
  userSecurityKeys.some((key, i, { length }) => {
    const res = u2f.checkSignature(request, response, key.publicKey);

    if (res.successful) {
      // return true to stop the .some from looping to other keys
      return true
    } else {
      if (length - 1 === i) reject({
        error: true,
        status: 400,
        message: res.errorMessage || 'Not a registered security key'
      });
    };
  })
};
```

Client-side script

```js
import { ensureSupport, sign, register } from "u2f-api";

const registerKey = () => {
  ensureSupport()
    .then(() => {
      // browser supports U2F
      register(requestFromServerScript)
        .then(registerResponse => {
          // send to server
        })
        .catch(() => {
          // error, user clicked on "cancel"?
        })
    })
    .catch(() => {
      // browser does not support U2F (looking at you, internet explorer)
    });
};

const signKey = () => {
  ensureSupport()
    .then(() => {
      // browser supports U2F

      /**
       * signRequestsFromServerScript can be an array of
       * requests, refer to server-side script "sign" function
       */
      sign(signRequestsFromServerScript)
        .then(signResponse => {
          // send to server
        })
        .catch(() => {
          // error, user clicked on "cancel"?
        })
    })
    .catch(() => {
      // browser does not support U2F (looking at you, internet explorer)
  });
};
```

Comment: If there is a better way to do it, please share :)